# Indexing into an array returns only "["

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have some data which is an array of arrays, each sub-array is length one and the only item in that array is an object with key value pairs. As an example:

```
const array = [[{'city': 'new york', 'state': 'ny'}], [{'city': 'dallas', 'state': 'tx'}], ,[{'city': 'los angeles', 'state': 'ca'}]]
```

I am trying to loop through this array and pull out only the cities. I can do that by running

```
array.forEach(item => console.log(item[0].city))
```

However, when I try this on my actual data (which I unfortunately cannot share) I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'city')

When I try to run just

```
array.forEach(item => console.log(item[0]))
```

the only thing that gets returned is a bunch of `[`, plus one `undefined` for the blank entry.

If it is relevant, the actual data that I am trying to index into is a column pulled from a Google Sheet.

Does anyone know why I am unable to properly iterate through my data and any possible solutions around it?

#### EDIT:

As Parvez pointed out, my array is being pulled from the data as an array of strings, rather than an array of arrays. That means that my data actually looks like

```
const array = ["[{'city': 'new york', 'state': 'ny'}]", "[{'city': 'dallas', 'state': 'tx'}]", "","[{'city': 'los angeles', 'state': 'ca'}]"]
```

If anyone has any suggestions for how to work with those sub-arrays so that I can pull out the relevant data, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The code you posted works as required. Perhaps the code you actually have is different

Comment: Unless you provide a [mre], it is very difficult for us to help.

Comment: You do not have to provide the real data, just any sample data that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: How are you getting a 2-dimensional array of objects from a Google Sheet?

Comment: Why have a sub-array if it's always just 1 element?

Comment: Looks like all the elements in the outer array are strings that look like js arrays.

Comment: @Unmitigated , Parvez figured out that my data is being pulled as an array of strings, not an array of arrays. I have updated my question to reflect the new data.

Comment: @Barmar The data is populating a google sheet from an API call, each sub-array is always one element because that's just how it gets put into the cell and it's a two dimensional array because the outer array is a column with each inner array being one of the cells in the column.

Answer (score 1):

My Answer:

```
const array = [[{'city': 'new york', 'state': 'ny'}], [{'city': 'dallas', 'state': 'tx'}], ,[{'city': 'los angeles', 'state': 'ca'}]]


array.map((ele)=> {
  const [{city, state}] = ele;
  console.log(city)
})
```

Hope it would be help to you.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why it returning an array of `[`, is probably because each element inside the outer array is a string like this:

```
const array = [
  "[{'city': 'new york', 'state': 'ny'}]",
  "[{'city': 'dallas', 'state': 'tx'}]",
  "",
  "[{'city': 'los angeles', 'state': 'ca'}]"
];
```

Thats why `array.forEach(item => console.log(item[0].city))` gives an error and `array.forEach(item => console.log(item[0]))` gives a weird array.

--EDIT--

If the strings are in a JSON compatible format then it becomes easy to parse it, like below:

`const newArray = array.map(data => JSON.parse(data));`

Then you should be able to access the *city* and *state* keys easily.

If the data is not in JSON compatible format then you have 2 options:

1. Modify the sources of this data (the API or wherever you get the data from) to be in JSON compatible format. Then you can use the above technique. (Recommended)
2. You are a utility functions which accepts the data as a string, parses it and then returns the values against the required keys

Comment: This looks like it was the problem. Do you have any suggestions for working around it?

Comment: You can maybe parse the string data. I've edited the answer to explain what I mean